# offline_access permission not present in Graph api explorer in facebook graph api

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

i've created a facebook Application today for my website i'm requesting access_token through javascript sdk with scope=manage_pages,offline_access,read_insights i figured out that **offline_access** was not given for the application newly created rest of the permission was granted but i've already made two application through that i can able to get offline_access scope for my access token my question is,

**Is there any updates included in the new Javascript sdk  .**

steps to reproduce:
1.create an application in facebook.

2.click edit application and at the left side links click graph api explorer.

3.In the graphi explorer choose your newly created application and.

4.click get_accestoken button dialogue box ->extended permission

5.select read_insights,manage_pages,offline_access checkboxes.click ok.

1. you can notice except offline_access other request are Present.

The access_token which you got from above steps will expires when session closed. so you can understand **offline_access** scope was not given.

Please some  one help me to get out of this ...
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the app setting called `deprecate offline_access` to `Disabled` in the advanced tab.

Comment: i couldn't understand what you are trying to say, are they remove offline_access scope? or i need to change some setting in my app?

Comment: yes, they are removing it.  But for you to get offline access (for now during the transition of deprecation), set that setting to disabled.

Comment: offline_access is being descoped. You can read more about it here https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/633/  For now though you can enable it again by following the steps DMCS outlined in your app settings. However, as they are deprecating it you should look at an alternative

Comment: @DMCS thanks a lot man its works for me now i just noticed the left settings

Comment: @DMCS  if they removed offline_access means how do i access the insights data when users not log-in to facebook ? is there any solutions for that.

Comment: You should use an **app** access token for insights, not a **user** access token.

Comment: Play around with your Grpah API and FQL's at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer.  You will learn a lot there.

Comment: is that enough to use  Application access_token for all the users page insights ?. i've gone through TommBs link ,  i'm wondering only we can extend the permission upto 60 days.

Comment: i've found some solution in this link to extending  the life span of access_token upto 60 days. this link might help  newbie like me . if there is any other solution please   add here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/offline-access-deprecation/